# AWS Lambda execution time greater than 10 seconds but less than 1 second locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nltk

Why would an AWS Lambda function execution time be drastically different than local run time?? I am using a python library (NLTK) and executing 1 specific function runs less than a second locally but when uploaded to AWS Lambda it takes more than 10 seconds. What are the reasons this could be due to? I was able to mimic the AWS Lambda server locally following AWS documentation and the execution time is greater than 10 seconds as well. Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

To see my files being uploaded to AWS lambda please see the following github link: https://github.com/jenkins6g/NLTKDebugging

Comment: you’re downloading a corpus of data, is that correct?

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured to run in a VPC? And when you say 10 seconds, what exactly are you measuring here?

Comment: check the memory configured for the function in aws.  lambda allocates cpu linearly in proportion to the amount of memory configured. the default of 128mb gives you about a 12th of full cpu core.  try bumping it up to 1gb.

Comment: @aws_apprentice the corpus was downloaded prior to uploading to AWS. It is in the zip folder.

Comment: @jarmod sorry for the confusion, I am assuming it is the execution time to run the lambda function. After executing the function, AWS gives a log that would include Duration.

Comment: @LexScarisbrick thank you for the suggestion, I bumped the memory up to 1792 MB and that decreased the execution time to 2209.68 ms which in my case is a significant improvement from 10+ seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I see that `Archive.zip` is 50 MB. Even if you're uploading that separately from individual executions of the Lambda (which you should do, in this case) you're still paying a significant network penalty.

You should measure the time when you invoke many of the lambda functions at once; this may amortize the time costs.

On the other hand, if you're only running one or a small number of functions, consider moving to an alternative tool. For example, you could set up a Lightsail instance with your libraries preloaded. You can reduce the costs by using a Batch instance (although this will add some latency to triggering your functions).

There are many ways to solve a problem, and if you describe more about the scale of your problem and your ultimate goals, it will be easier to recommend the right workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I ended up increasing the memory configuration from 128 mb to 1792 MB as @LexScarisbrick suggested above although AWS logs Max Memory Used as 167 MB. There doesn't seem to be a greater performance improvement with increased memory. Thank you all for the insights for everyone who commented. I was also look into alternative solutions for scaling and a better performance.